# node.js express-uploadFile undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a .txt file with the middleware express-uploadFile. However, when I try to test it my file is undefined.

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

var app = express()

app.use(fileUpload());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


app.post('/send', function(req, res){ 
  console.log(req.files.UploadBox);
  console.log(req.body.Question);
});
```

```html
 <form id="Izone" action="/send/" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">

     <input type="text" name="Question" id="Question" placeholder="Question" autofocus autocomplete="off"><br/><br/>


    <label for="UploadBox" id="UploadBoxStyle"> Upload File </label>
    <input type="file" name="UploadBox" id="UploadBox">


   <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send"/>

 </form>
```

req.body.Question works fine. However, req.files gives me undefined.

I don't know if the issue is bodyParser or fileupload itselft.

Comment: strange, works for me

Comment: I tried with a .png file and it works. However, with a .txt file it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: works with txt file for me